# I want set this box centered

Tags: html, css, simplemodal

I'm trying to set this modal-message centered but it always falling to the left side, I've tried with `margin: 0 auto; float: center` or `left: 0` and `right: 0` but this doesn't work.

```css
.descrizione { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
} 

.descrizione .cancel { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
} 

.descrizione:target { 
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 

.messaggio { 
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
} 

.light .messaggio { 
  border-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
} 

.messaggio h2 { 
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2767ce;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
} 

.messaggio .chiudi { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
} 

.messaggio .chiudi:hover { 
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
} 

.messaggio .testo { 
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
} 
.messaggio p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
} 

.messaggio p:last-child { 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="descrizione" id="hub">
<div class="messaggio">
<h2>hub</h2>
<a class="chiudi" href="#">&times;</a>

<div class="testo">
<p>Questa &egrave; una breve descrizione che deve essere modificate dal propietario della pagina di mc-ita, si prega di modificarla al pi&ugrave; presto</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

PS: This message appears after you have clicked a button.

Comment: Have you tried adding a containing div with width 100% and then putting margin: auto on the descrizione div?

Comment: You said you tried `margin: 0 auto` but adding `.messaggio { margin: 0 auto; }` centers it.... you're saying that doesn't work?

Comment: yes michael coker

Comment: yes jonathan holland

Comment: @Lafa: to ping a user here, you must use a `@` with a username. Tab completion is available. You can either edit those messages if you are quick, or delete them and post them again.

Comment: @Lafa you sure about that? seems to work... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/WOxoYb

Comment: but this isn't a my site this is an html inside another html

Comment: https://www.minecraft-italia.it/lista-server-italiani/axelgames-12408 this is the link

Comment: ok now it works i don't know how i did it, i've copied the codepen of micheal cocker and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with flexbox, modifications are noted in the CSS but basically:

- Add `width:100%;` & `height: 100%;` to `html, body{}`
- Set `.descrizione` to `display: flex;` and align vertically with `justify-content: center;` and horizontally with `align-items: center;`

Snippet:

```css
/* add these */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.descrizione {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; */
  transition: opacity 400ms;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* add these */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.descrizione .cancel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
}

.descrizione:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.messaggio {
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  /* add these */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.light .messaggio {
  border-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.messaggio h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2767ce;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.messaggio .chiudi {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.messaggio .chiudi:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.messaggio .testo {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.messaggio p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.messaggio p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="descrizione" id="hub">
  <div class="messaggio">
    <h2>hub</h2>
    <a class="chiudi" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="testo">
      <p>Questa &egrave; una breve descrizione che deve essere modificate dal propietario della pagina di mc-ita, si prega di modificarla al pi&ugrave; presto</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
messagio{
margin: auto;
}
```

Because messagio is only 300px and it's container is spanning width of parent, you must use the margin to center it.

Another way is with Flexbox setting parent to flex and justify content center, or positioning left: 50% and minusing half of the width (150px).. But I think margin auto fits best.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
margin:15% auto;
```

to `.messagio` css class...